# Best Practices on namespaces : on Symfony, difference of perfs when using (sub)namespaces?

Tags: php, symfony, namespaces, fosrestbundle

I'm building an API and I would ask something about using namespaces on a Symfony2 controller.
Is there a real difference doing :

```
<?php

namespace My\APIBundle\Controller;

use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\View,
    FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\Post,
    FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\Get;
use [...]

class MyRestController extends Controller {

    [...]

    /**
     * @View()
     * @Get()
     */
    public function getAction(Thing $thing) {
        return $thing;
    }

    /**
     * @View()
     * @Post()
     */
    public function postAction() {

    }
```

or doing

```
<?php

namespace My\APIBundle\Controller;

use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
use [...]

class MyRestController extends Controller {

    [...]

    /**
     * @Rest\View()
     * @Rest\Get()
     */
    public function getAction(Thing $thing) {
        return $thing;
    }

    /**
     * @Rest\View()
     * @Rest\Post()
     */
    public function postAction() {

    }
```

Would the alias load everything in the given namespace, losing perfs ?
Or will it load only annoted classes, unitary ?

Comment: second example will load all classes under Annotation directory.

Comment: Nope and nope.  Classes are loaded when they are needed.  You can see this if you add some debug statements to the class loader.  Regardless, any performance difference will be essentially non measurable.